# Is it possible to get an asp.net 'OnClicked' callback in javascript to call a function in a web control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, callback, onclick

It does seem like it wouldn't be possible since callback functions seem to be page specific but in case it's possible I'd like to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `static` page methods marked with the [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.aspx) attribute using [ASP.NET Ajax](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx) if you configure the `ScriptManager` to do so:

```
<form id="form" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"
        EnablePageMethods="true" />
    .
    .
    .
</form>

[WebMethod]
public static int Foo(string bar)
{
    return 42;
}
```

Then in your client-side code:

```
function callFoo(bar)
{
    return PageMethods.Foo(bar);
}
```

You can also do the same [with jQuery](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/):

```
function callFoo(bar)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YourPage.aspx/Foo",
        data: {
            "bar": bar
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(message) {
            // Do something.
        }
    });
}
```